# Kendo Grid column resize event makes column wider

Tags: html, kendo-grid

I’m using a Kendo Grid with a lot of columns, but some of them are hidden by default.
It seems like a Kendo grid bug, but when I try to resize a column it instantly makes itself twice as wider.
All columns have a width set as percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Grid’s logic that computes column’s width. If width is a percentage and some are hidden, width is converted to pixels wrong.
The solution is to adjust width for each column (on start and column show\hide event), convert to px and assign to html elements.

Invoke on Grid's `dataBound` event after show\hide events:

```
function adjustGridVisibleColumnsPercentageWidth () {
    var $theGrid = $(“theGrid”);

    var proportions = [];

    var sumOfVisiblePercentage = _($theGrid.getKendoGrid().columns).filter(function (el) {
        return ((el.hidden === undefined || el.hidden === false)
            && _(el.width).isString() && el.width.indexOf("%") >= 0);
    }).reduce(function (memo, el) {
        var onlyNumber = el.width.substring(0, el.width.length - 1);
        var asNumber = parseInt(onlyNumber, 10);
        if (_(asNumber).isNumber()) {
            proportions.push(asNumber);
            return memo + asNumber;
        }
        return memo;
    }, 0);

    var gridWidth = $theGrid.find(".k-grid-header").width();

    var applyProportions = function (ix, el) {
        var cw = Math.round(gridWidth * (proportions[ix] / sumOfVisiblePercentage));
        el.style.width = cw + "px";
    };

    $theGrid.find(".k-grid-header-wrap table[role='grid'] colgroup col").each(applyProportions);
    $theGrid.find(".k-grid-content table[role='grid'] colgroup col").each(applyProportions);
}
```

This code computes proportions for visible columns basing on declared width percentage. Then html structure is adjusted.

Comment: I tried to implement your answer but it did not work: http://dojo.telerik.com/EJeNo

Comment: @Silvanmidix - in your dojo there are some errors: 1) you must link underscore.js; 2) the event is dataBound not dateBound; 3) you renamed $theGrid to theGrid variable, but not everythere; 4) you have column widths in pixels not percentage; SO, I fixed your dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/aZiYe

Comment: Check this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/aSUbO. Much cleaner, when I add the detailini function and then hide a column they magically do what you you need a custom function for.

Comment: @Silvanmidix in the latest dojo there is no adjustGridVisibleColumnsPercentageWidth() code so it can't work. And columns are in pixels (it has to be defined as "10%", )

Comment: -> works in this one with the detailinit function (and pixel width for columns as well) http://dojo.telerik.com/aSUbO